# Is there anyway to use an office word application written by vb.net in all computers without error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project that creates a microsoft word document and puts results in it. It works correctly in my own computer but in other computers, this error will be reported:
Microsoft.interop.word not found
Or
Microsoft word can not read this file.
....
I have checked "microsoft office 2007 interop assemblies" in prerequisites at the moment of publishing application. But it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Is Word installed on those other machines? "Interop" is short for "interoperate". You cannot interoperate with an application if that application doesn't exist on the local machine.

Comment: If you put your results in an HTML document instead, then it's a fair bet all the other machines will have software installed that can open it

Comment: There are a lot of other tools and methods available that can be used for presenting information and deployed with your application before resorting to Word and relying on office interops

Comment: Yes of course! Other machines have installed word.

Comment: I think i should edit my publish prerequisites or my project references. But i don't know what should i do exactly.